# java garbage collection due to mulitly object reference

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Will the `car_object_1` be able to garbage collected? Somebody maintain that as `car_object_1` has two reference so it will never be garaged collected. Is it true?

```
Car createACar()
{
  Car c = new MyCar(); //car_object_1 was created 
  return c;
}

void use_the_car()
{
  Car c2 = createACar();
  c2.run();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're talking nonsense. Assuming there's nothing within `run()` which stashes a reference somewhere, the car is eligible for garbage collection after the `c2.run();` statement in `use_the_car`.

Java is *not* reference counted - even circular references aren't a problem (e.g. where a `Car` and a `Driver` have a reference to each other, but nothing has a reference to either of them).

Perhaps the person you were talking to was thinking of a slightly different situation?

Comment: +1: There is only one reference to the object at any time, after `use_the_car` returns, there are no more references. (if there was a statement after `c2.run()` it would not be eligible until the reference goes out of scope.